# Get All Groups And subGroups and all members from LDAP

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

I'm trying to get all groups and their sub groups and members of each group from active directory then link each group of it's subgroup in tree structure then store result in database, so that I can find out what is the parent and the child of each group.

How can I convert the following code using `DirectoryServices` to test performance?

```
public static List<Group>getUsers()
    {

        // create the "context" in which to operate - your domain here, 
        // as the old-style NetBIOS domain, and the container where to operate in
        PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "lin.proximus.com");

        // define a "prototype" - an example of what you're searching for
        // Here: just a simple GroupPrincipal - you want all groups
        GroupPrincipal prototype = new GroupPrincipal(ctx);

        // define a PrincipalSearcher to find those principals that match your prototype
        PrincipalSearcher searcher = new PrincipalSearcher(prototype);

        // define a list of strings to hold the group names        
        List<Group> groupNames = new List<Group>();
        int counter = 0;
        // iterate over the result of the .FindAll() call
        foreach (var gp in searcher.FindAll())
        {

            // cast result to GroupPrincipal
            GroupPrincipal groupPrincipal = gp as GroupPrincipal;

            // if everything - grab the group's name and put it into the list
            if (groupPrincipal == null) continue;

            Group group = new Group();
            group.Name = groupPrincipal.Name;
            group.Description = groupPrincipal.Description;
            AddSubGroups(groupPrincipal, ref group);
            AddMemebers(groupPrincipal, ref group);
            counter++;
            groupNames.Add(group);
            Console.WriteLine(counter);
            if (counter > 10000)
                return groupNames;
        }
        return groupNames;
    }

    private static void AddSubGroups(GroupPrincipal gp,ref Group gr)
    {
        gr.SubCounts = 0;
        if (gp.GetGroups().Count() <= 0) return;

        gr.SubCounts = gp.GetGroups().Count();
        gr.SubGroups = new List<string>();
        foreach (var principal in gp.GetGroups())
        {
            gr.SubGroups.Add(principal.Name);
        }
    }

    private static void AddMemebers(GroupPrincipal gp, ref Group gr)
    {
        if (gp.GetMembers().Count() <= 0) return;

        gr.Users = new List<string>();

        foreach (Principal principal in gp.GetMembers())
        {
            gr.Users.Add(principal.Name);
        }
    }
```

Comment: To get all the results, set your `PageSize` property on the `DirectorySearcher` to e.g. 500 or so, to get "paged searching", e.g. retrieval of more than 1000 objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I second Marc's suggestion - use paging and the appropriate pagesize property values to increase performance. AFAIK, paging is virtually essential if you're tring to get a attribute that might have > 999 values e.g. a group's membership.